# Where is layer module defined in PyCaffe

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am modifying a [Caffe tutorial](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/pascal-multilabel-with-datalayer.ipynb) to implement a neural network, but I am struggling to identify where some of the pycaffe modules are location in order to see certain function definitions.

For example, the tutorial mentions:

```
import caffe
from caffe import layers a L, params as P
....
L.Convolution(bottom, kernel_size=ks, stride=stride, num_output=nout, pad=pad, group=group)
L.InnerProduct(bottom, num_output=nout)
L.ReLU(fc, in_place=True)
...
```

Where can I find these function definitions and where can I see what other types of layers are pre-defined? I see that `layers` and `params` are [defined here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/net_spec.py) but there's no mention of the types (e.g. `layers.Convolution`, etc).

The reason I am trying to figure this out is because there are other prototxt parameters left out of the pycaffe tutorials that I would like to be able to define from Python when generating the prototxts. These include, `blob_lr` and `include{phase: TRAIN}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the `blob_lr` and `phase` like this:

```
import caffe
from caffe import layers a L, params as P

ns = caffe.NetSpec()
ns.conv = L.Convolution(bottom, convolution_param={'kernel_size':ks,
                                                   'stride':stride,
                                                   'num_output':nout, 
                                                   'pad':pad, 
                                                   'group':group},
                                param=[{'lr_mult':1, 'decay_mult':1},
                                       {'lr_mult':2, 'decay_mult':0}],
                                include={'phase': caffe.TRAIN})
```

You can see some more examples in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35967589/1714410).

Comment: Is this new syntax? A lot of this is different than the tutorial provided by the Caffe developers. For instance, putting all of that info into a `convolution_param` dict

Comment: @marcman I don't think it's new, it's a slightly different way of providing the parameters. I find it more clear this way. It's definitely easier this way to provide parameters that are of "repeated" type (e.g., the blob param `'lr_mult'`).

Comment: @Shai how can we specify the blob names and layer names seperately?

Comment: @gauravgupta you have an optional `name` argument