# DataLayer placement in the .prototxt file generated by Shai's LSTM implementation

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Regarding the answer provided by @Shai in [LSTM module for Caffe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32225388/lstm-module-for-caffe/35967589#35967589), where `caffe.NetSpec()` is used to explicitly unroll LSTM units in time for training.

Using this code implementation, why does the `"DummyData"` layer, or any data layer used instead as input `X`, appears at the end of the `t0` time step, just before `"t1/lstm/Mx"` in the prototxt file? I don't get it...

A manipulation (cut / paste) is hence needed.

Comment: BTW there were some typos in the code I posted. I corrected them, you can check it out again now.

Comment: I did not intend to offend you, I am sorry if it can be perceived that way! On the contrary, I thank you for implementing the LSTM, which works pretty well!
I used it and obtained good results, I also stacked lstm using these functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Shai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1714410/shai)'s NetSpec [implementation of LSTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32225388/lstm-module-for-caffe?lq=1) unrolls the net in time. Hence for every time step there is an LSTM unit with shared weights across time steps.
The "bottom" for each unit in time (e.g. `t1/lstm/Mx`) is a different time step of the input X.

By the way, I suggest you use `draw_net.py` caffe utility to draw the resulting prototxt and see the flow of data and the temporal repetitions of the unrolled LSTM unit.

Here's how the unrolled net looks like:
[image]
You can see the components of the three LSTM cells, and the **different** temporal slices of `X` going to each temporal unrolled LSTM unit.

Comment: My concern is about the .prototxt file generated. Despite that the MemoryData layer is created before the unrolling phase, it appears after the t0 timestep, just before "t1/lstm/Mx".

Comment: @FlorianMutel I assumed the data `X` contains all time steps in it, and therefore there is a temporal `"Slice"` layer before the different temporal slices are fed into the LSTM. You can ignore `X` and make `DummyData` for each time step separately.

Comment: You can think of `Slice1` `Slice2` and `Slice3` as `t0/x`, `t1/x` and `t2/x` respectively.

Comment: I was using "bottom = 'nameOfLayer' " and switching to 'ns.layer' it corrected the placement of my dataLayer. Thank you for your time and the draw_net trick

Comment: @FlorianMutel glad I could help, and I am happy to learn that this LSTM implementation worked for you.