# Output of LSTM in many-to-many scenario in Caffe (C or H)

Tags: neural-network, caffe, recurrent-neural-network, lstm, pycaffe

The code for a single LSTM cell is below (copied from Caffe src/layers). My question is, which of the top outputs is connected to the next layer (typically an embedding or a SoftMax).

Is it the C-top or the H-top?

From the code, here are the definitions of C and H.

```
Dtype* C = top[0]->mutable_cpu_data();
Dtype* H = top[1]->mutable_cpu_data();
```

The LSTM cell code

```
template <typename Dtype>
void LSTMUnitLayer<Dtype>::Forward_cpu(const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& bottom,
    const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& top) {
  const int num = bottom[0]->shape(1);
  const int x_dim = hidden_dim_ * 4;
  const Dtype* C_prev = bottom[0]->cpu_data();
  const Dtype* X = bottom[1]->cpu_data();
  const Dtype* cont = bottom[2]->cpu_data();
  Dtype* C = top[0]->mutable_cpu_data();
  Dtype* H = top[1]->mutable_cpu_data();
  for (int n = 0; n < num; ++n) {
    for (int d = 0; d < hidden_dim_; ++d) {
      const Dtype i = sigmoid(X[d]);
      const Dtype f = (*cont == 0) ? 0 :
          (*cont * sigmoid(X[1 * hidden_dim_ + d]));
      const Dtype o = sigmoid(X[2 * hidden_dim_ + d]);
      const Dtype g = tanh(X[3 * hidden_dim_ + d]);
      const Dtype c_prev = C_prev[d];
      const Dtype c = f * c_prev + i * g;
      C[d] = c;
      const Dtype tanh_c = tanh(c);
      H[d] = o * tanh_c;
    }
    C_prev += hidden_dim_;
    X += x_dim;
    C += hidden_dim_;
    H += hidden_dim_;
    ++cont;
  }
}
```

**Question**,

So if we define a layer like the one below, then the top (named '`lstm1`') is referring to which output, C or H?

```
layer {
  name: "lstm1"
  type: "LSTM"
  bottom: "fc6-reshape"
  bottom: "reshape-cm"
  top: "lstm1"
  recurrent_param {
    num_output: 8
    weight_filler {
      type: "uniform"
      min: -0.01
      max: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you are mixing two layers: `"LSTM"` and `"LSTMUnit"`.

Comment: Thanks, Shai, I zero'ed in to the place where the core LSTM computation is happening. Is there some other place to look?

Comment: I'm afraid i never got too deep with the "standard" LSTM layer. I used my own [unrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35967589/1714410).

Comment: My question isn't implementation specific. The notation, 'c' and 'h' are standard notations. Looking at your implementation, after every time-step calculation (c, h, lstm_weights = single_time_step_lstm( ns, h, c, xt[t], 't'+str(t)+'/', lstm_output, lstm_weights)), you append the 'h' values to the tops (tops.append(h)). So the cell output, c, is an internal memory state. Its not connected to any other input (except its own). Do I have that right?

Comment: yes, but I suppose you can get a clearer idea from the attached diagrams