# how to achieve Bi-LSTM in caffe?

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe, lstm

i am doing a project and want to achieve a bilstm in caffe,but i don't know how to do .Can it be modified directly in the prototxt.Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: You can unroll the model yourself using `pycaffe` and `caffe.NetSpec()` interface. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35967589/1714410) how to do so for regular LSTM net.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,i will try it .i have another question,can i use the "propagate_down" parameter directly in the prototxt  to achieve the backward pass?@Shai

Comment: I don't understand your question. feel free to ask a new question

Comment: Would you explain how to achieve the backward passes using the pycaffe and caffe.NetSpec() interface?reverse the input?@Shai

Comment: `caffe.NetSpec` interface is only used to programitically create the net structure (i.e., the prototxt file) the training/validation is carried out in the same manner as every net in caffe.