# How to model Recurrent Convolutional Neural Networks in Caffe?

Tags: c++, caffe, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am quite new to the Caffe framework, only recently starting to use it.

I understand that modelling CNNs is allowed, however, is it possible to combine RNNs (not much experience with these) and CNNs together, to form a recurrent convolutional neural network?

I am currently looking at: http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/ for Caffe knowledge and following some tutorials online. Any other tutorials which you recommend would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: For what reason do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Although Caffe provides Recurrent Layer, unfortunately the documentation is terrible. This is the only legit example of LSTMs that I know of that is written in Caffe: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~lisa_anne/LRCN_video

Answer (score -1):

Look at caffe'a [`"Recurrent"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/recurrent.html) layer, there's also an `"LSTM"` layer.
If you are looking for something more complex, you might consider unrolling the net yourself, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35967589/1714410) for an example.

Comment: I considered both but I dont think any of them is convolutional. I think unrolling is the only way to implement it.